# How can i compare string and character types?

Tags: java

```
    System.out.print("Enter C for Celsius or F for Farenheit: ");
    String optionLetter = kb.readLine();

    if (optionLetter == 'c')
    {
        System.out.print("Enter temperature: ");
        double tempC = Integer.parseInt(kb.readLine());

        double degreesF = (9 * (tempC/5) +32);

        System.out.println(tempC + " celcius is " + degreesF + " in farenheit.");
    }
}
```

so the user can input only one character either C or c....so basically in the readLine, it cant read Character data types...so i am force to declare it in string but when i use it in a condition in the if statement i get the error during compiling that string and char are incompatible types...
i know its incompatible but what can i do??? i cant declare the variable optionLetter as character and also i just need to check if the user input c????

how am i going to check...??

i tried the .equals method and still it wont work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try taking the first character of the string:

```
if (optionLetter.charAt(0) == 'c')
```

Or you could compare it to the string "c" instead of the character 'c'.

```
if (optionLetter.equals("c"))
```

You can even make it case insensitive:

```
if (optionLetter.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
```

Double quotes (`"`) indicate `String` objects, while single quotes (`'`) indicate `char` primitives. The `String` class has a method `equals` to compare it to other objects. To compare chars, you can just use `==`.

Comment: @Rae Sorry that was a typo, it's supposed to be `"c"`.

Comment: it works!!!! thanks..... so i know now that double quotes and single quotes vary..... thanks so much... i will start reading about it more... :D

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to compare the first character in the String. It should only have one character, even so you can't compare the whole string to a char.

Your code will be:

```
if(optionLetter.charAt(0) == 'c') 
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

Comparing it to the string c will also work:

```
if(optionLetter.equals("c")) 
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: ohh!!! thank you so much... i didnt know about this code where in there is a number 0...i will start reading about it now...thanks!!!

Comment: The zero is referring to the very first character in the string. In the example: "String abc = "abcdef";", abc.charAt(0) == a, abc.charAt(1) == b, and so on, until abc.charAt(5) == f.

Answer (score 1):

Using single quotes in Java indicates a `char`, while double quotes indicates a `String`. Switch your single quotes around c to double quotes and try using `.equals()`.

Comment: woah.... thanks...thanks to you i know now that double quotes and single quotes vary.....thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make it case insensitive with something like

```
if (optionLetter.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
    // ...
} else if (optionLetter.equalsIgnoreCase("f")) {
    // ...
}
```

or you might prefer to check the first character like

```
if (Character.toLowerCase(optionLetter.charAt(0)) == 'c') {
    // ...
} else if (Character.toLowerCase(optionLetter.charAt(0)) == 'f') {
    // ...
}
```